# Program assistance with JSONP Script Insertion and Callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jsonp

I'm having trouble writing this code that will use JSONP Script Insertion Technique and a Callback Function.  I must use http://legacy.jefferson.kctcs.edu/users/mark.prather/states.txt for the URL. This is a sample of what's on the webpage

```
function getStateData( [
{State:"Alabama", Abbreviation:"AL", Statehood:1819, Capital:"Montgomery"},
{State, "Alaska", Abbreviation:"AK", Statehood:1959, Capital:"Juneau"},
{State:"Arizona", Abbreviation:"AZ", Statehood:1912, Capital:"Phoenix"},
] );
```

I must use getStateData(sData) as the name of mycallback and sData is supposed to hold the data for the array. Then I must have a form that allows a user to select a state and get the requested data, which is the State, Abbreviation, Statehood, and Capital. Below is a portion of my form.

```
<form>
    <p>
        <select>
            <option value="AL" selected>Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
```

My largest issue is the fact that the URL is a function already instead of raw data. I'm not looking for handouts, just help. This is what I've gotten so far. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.   https://jsfiddle.net/MaNBeAsT515/ppp0dxwm/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there's two things you need to change to get this to work in a jsfiddle:

1. Since you are calling a service that only supports http, you cannot use a jsfiddle that uses https.
2. You need to change the jsfiddle so the JavaScript is in the `<head>` element. This is because your function needs to be in the global scope since you are calling it from an `onclick` attribute.

After that, I think you just need to change how you are dealing with the returned data. It is an array, but you want to get the data for one state using its abbreviation. One way to deal with that is to create a map object from the array.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7au5tfx7/)

---

Here's a function that converts the array into a map object:

```
function createStateMap(states) {
    var map = {};
    states.forEach(function(state) {
        map[state.Abbreviation] = state;
    });
    return map;
}
```

---

I'm not doing it in the jsfiddle above, but I think you should remove the previously inserted `<script>` element before creating a new one. You should probably also set the `type` attribute of the `<script>` element.

```
function insertURL() {
    var oldScript = document.getElementById('stateScript');
    if (oldScript) {
        oldScript.parentNode.removeChild(oldScript);
    }

    var url = " http://legacy.jefferson.kctcs.edu/users/mark.prather/states.txt"; 
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.setAttribute('id', 'stateScript');                   
    newScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');                   
    newScript.setAttribute('src', url);                   
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript); 
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7au5tfx7/1/)

Comment: Okay thank you. It was actually my first time using jsfiddle with a question such as this.

Comment: @RobertCHerrington - It was my first jsonp call. I removed my answer that showed how to do this with JQuery because I figured you really didn't want that. If you want to see it, I can undelete it.

Comment: That's alright thank you for the assistance! I'll do some comparing to see how/ what I should have done to mine the first time around.